# Python: how to assign unique IDs to pandas dataframe entries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dafarame like the following:

```
df
    Name1   Name2
0   John    Jack
1   John    Albert
2   Jack    Eva
3   Albert  Sara
4   Eva     Sara
```

I want to assign to each a name a unique `ID`. So:

```
df
    Name1   Name2      ID1     ID2
0   John    Jack        0       1
1   John    Albert      0       2
2   Jack    Eva         1       3
3   Albert  Sara        2       5
4   Eva     Sara        3       5
```

Comment: Is it important which name gets which number?

Comment: No, it is not important. Just unique IDs between 0 and 1

Answer (score 3):

First flatten values by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and reshape by original `df`, use DataFrame constructor and create columns names, last `join` to original:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.factorize(df.values.ravel())[0].reshape(df.shape))
df1.columns = ['ID{}'.format(x+1) for x in range(len(df1.columns))]
print (df1)
   ID1  ID2
0    0    1
1    0    2
2    1    3
3    2    4
4    3    4

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
    Name1   Name2  ID1  ID2
0    John    Jack    0    1
1    John  Albert    0    2
2    Jack     Eva    1    3
3  Albert    Sara    2    4
4     Eva    Sara    3    4
```

Create `MultiIndex Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), create `id`s by [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) and for `DataFrame` [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), then `rename` columns and add to original by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = df.stack()
df = df.join(pd.Series(pd.factorize(s)[0], index=s.index)
               .unstack()
               .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('Name','ID')))
print (df)
    Name1   Name2  ID1  ID2
0    John    Jack    0    1
1    John  Albert    0    2
2    Jack     Eva    1    3
3  Albert    Sara    2    4
4     Eva    Sara    3    4
```

Similar alternative:

```
s = df.stack()
s[:] = pd.factorize(s)[0]
df = df.join(s.unstack().rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('Name','ID')))
print (df)
    Name1   Name2  ID1  ID2
0    John    Jack    0    1
1    John  Albert    0    2
2    Jack     Eva    1    3
3  Albert    Sara    2    4
4     Eva    Sara    3    4
```

Comment: Albert gets a `2` in your solution in both columns. OP specified `2` and `4`.

Comment: @timgeb - yes, I notice it, I hope it is typo. It looks like it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not important which name gets which number, you can also consider

```
df.join(df.stack().astype('category').cat.codes.unstack() 
          .rename(columns=lambda c: c.replace('Name', 'ID')))
```

which produces

```
    Name1   Name2  ID1  ID2
0    John    Jack    3    2
1    John  Albert    3    0
2    Jack     Eva    2    1
3  Albert    Sara    0    4
4     Eva    Sara    1    4
```